# Getting the output from an API request (client-side)

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, rest

Note: I am inexperienced with APIs, JSON, REST, etc.

I am trying to implement FilePreviews into my site. Its purpose is to take the url for any file type and convert it into a JPG or PNG.

**JavaScript**

```
var previews = new FilePreviews({
  debug: true,
  apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY'
});

var url = 'http://i.imgur.com/HQB8wtI.jpg';

var options = {
  size: {
    width: 100,
    height: 999
  },
  metadata: ['exif', 'ocr', 'psd'],
  format: 'jpg'
};

previews.generate(url, options);
```

The request is received by the developer's app. The following results are shown in the site dashboard of the developer's app:

```
{
    "preview": {
        "resized": true,
        "size": {
            "height": "178",
            "width": "100"
        },
        "page": 1,
        "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/[removed for privacy]/ec210ecf45d9d190539a241462c621f75adf2d4f835fb394a8d738d09fd412d6/HQB8wtI_100x999_1.jpg",
        "requested_size": "100x999",
        "original_size": {
            "height": "1024",
            "width": "576"
        }
    },
    "id": "25841aca-e176-4cf7-ac1d-b01ce604a765",
    "user_data": null,
    "status": "success",
    "url": "https://api.filepreviews.io/v2/previews/25841aca-e176-4cf7-ac1d-b01ce604a765/",
    "thumbnails": [
        {
            "resized": true,
            "size": {
                "height": "178",
                "width": "100"
            },
            "page": 1,
            "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/[removed for privacy]/ec210ecf45d9d190539a241462c621f75adf2d4f835fb394a8d738d09fd412d6/HQB8wtI_100x999_1.jpg",
            "requested_size": "100x999",
            "original_size": {
                "height": "1024",
                "width": "576"
            }
        }
    ],
    "original_file": {
        "metadata": {
            "ocr": null,
            "psd": null,
            "exif": null
        },
        "size": 82022,
        "extension": "jpg",
        "total_pages": 1,
        "encoding": "binary",
        "name": "HQB8wtI",
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "image"
    }
}
```

My question is: How do I get the url for the file preview into my site? Each file is referenced dynamically and there will be many on a page for most areas of my site. There seems to be no consistency in how FilePreviews is generating the folder on AWS S3, so I can't even use a clever PHP fix to solve it.

Anyone care to assist and show me the ways of this programming world?

Comment: Where is the code you are using to make the API request client-side? That response will be the JSON you posted (or can be converted to it). In that object is the url for the relevant thumbnail(s) i.e. `thumbnails[0].url`.

Comment: @DaveAnderson They haven't provided any client-side api request code. That's all I have from them. :/ When running the JS above in Fiddle, I get the results posted above, located in their site's dashboard.

Comment: ` The developer has been no help` except by giving you the exact information you need. Perhaps that's information they give to developers

Comment: Perhaps you need to [learn how to use any API](https://www.codecademy.com/apis) and apply it to FilePreviews. The site is only going to tell you the specifics of their API not how to use them in general.

Comment: I am not a developer. I am a hobbyist with a day job first and a steep learning curve ahead of me. I am trying, but I have a lot to learn, @JaromandaX. Not everyone on this site can be a veritable wealth of information - some of us need assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @DaveAnderson.

Comment: I understand. My point was your `was no helpl` comment was unwarranted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with FilePreviews, but this is how I expect it should work.

First, you add an image tag in your HTML, at the spot where you want the thumbnail to appear. Give it an id, for example "thumb":

```
<img id="thumb"/>
```

Then, modify the last line of your script as follows:

```
previews.generate(url, options, onPreviewReceived);
```

The third parameter is a callback function we must define elsewhere in the script. I have called it onPreviewReceived, but you can choose your own name. It is called when the result is received. You can define the callback function as follows:

```
function onPreviewReceived(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        var thumbnailUrl = result.thumbnails[0].url;  // but see assumption
        document.getElementById("thumb").setAttribute("src", thumbnailUrl);
    }
}
```

This function assigns the url, obtained from the result, to the src attribute of the img tag.

**Assumption**: I expect the 'result' to be as described in your question. However, [the client library documentation](https://github.com/GetBlimp/filepreviews.js) indicates that you will get a different result and that you should have a thumbnailUrl assignment like this:

```
var thumbnailUrl = result.previewUrl;
```

So please try that as well.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a useful response! I look forward to trying this (or at the very least starting to walk in the right direction) tonight when I get home. :)